# Android: Is it possible to have same-signature app modules, but only one is on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, digital-signature

Android documentation says that multiple apps having the same signature can be seen by the system as a single app made of modules, which can be upgraded independently.

I would like to know if this happens even when one app is distributed via Google Play and another is distributed in an independent way, provided the signature is the same.

Comment: "if this happens" -- if *what* happens?

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean: do the apps work and can they be upgraded, one via Google Play, the other independently? And, is it compliant with Google Play rules?

Comment: "do the apps work and can they be upgraded, one via Google Play, the other independently?" -- um, they should. The fact that they happen to be signed by the same signing key is irrelevant. They are independent apps; upgrading them is also independent. The signing key only comes into play if the apps interact (e.g., `signature`-level permissions). "is it compliant with Google Play rules?" -- that's off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare "App modularity: Android allows apps signed by the same certificate to run in the same process, if the applications so requests, so that the system treats them as a single application. In this way you can deploy your app in modules, and users can update each of the modules independently."
I just would like to know if one of these modules can be distributed independently instead of Google Play